# GCC error with SFINAE in trailing return type

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, c++14, sfinae

In my code below, my intention is to define `Weighted<T>::operator+=` only if template parameter `T` has `operator+=` and `operator*=`. It works fine on MSVC14, but GCC (tested with 6.3.0) fails with error "no match for ‘operator*=’" at the indicated location (when `T` doesn't have an `operator*=`).

```
template<typename T>
struct Weighted {
    double weight;
    T value;

    // ...

    // weighted mean
    template<typename U=T>
    auto operator+=(const Weighted<U>& other) -> decltype(value += other.value, value*=1.0, *this) {
// ***COMPILE ERROR*** ---------------------------------------------------->    ~~~~~^~~~~

        value *= weight;
        value += other.weight*other.value;
        weight += other.weight;
        value /= weight;
        return *this;
    }

    // scale weight
    Weighted<T>& operator*=(double multiplier) {
        weight *= multiplier;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

How should I be doing this? If the problem is with the version of compiler, is there an easy workaround to avoid having to upgrade the compiler?

Comment: Which version of `gcc` are you using? Recent version happily accept this code.

Comment: @lubgr I'm using GCC 6.3.0

Comment: Please make a complete example that causes a compilation failure.

Comment: `value*=1.0` doesn't depend on any deduced template parameter so you're not getting any SFINAE. Also, should it be possible that `U` is not `T`?

Comment: @Mark `U` should always be the same as `T`. Can you show me a better way to check that `T` has `operator*=(double)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename U=T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U,T>::value>>
auto operator+=(const Weighted<U>& other) -> decltype(value += other.value, std::declval<U&>()*=1.0, *this) {
    // ...
}
```

Also added a check on first line to constrain that `U` and `T` are same.

Comment: I see you've already figured it out. :) Note that you could've also written `value *= other.weight` instead of the `declval`, just like the check for `+=`.

Comment: Better to make U non deducible -> `const Weighted<T>& other`

Answer (score 0):

I would do that way:

```
#include  <experimental/type_traits>

using std::experimental::is_detected;

template <typename T, typename U>
using plus_equal_t = decltype(std::declval<T&>() += std::declval<U>());

template <typename T, typename U>
using time_equal_t = decltype(std::declval<T&>() += std::declval<U>());

// Define traits
template <typename T, typename U>
using has_plus_equal = is_detected<plus_equal_t, T, U>;

template <typename T, typename U>
using has_time_equal = is_detected<time_equal_t, T, U>;



template<typename T>
struct Weighted {
    double weight;
    T value;

    // ...

    // weighted mean
    template<typename U=T,
             std::enable_if_t<has_plus_equal<U, U>::value
                              && has_time_equal<U, double>::value, int> = 0>
    Weighted& operator+=(const Weighted<T>& other) {
        value *= weight;
        value += other.weight*other.value;
        weight += other.weight;
        value /= weight;
        return *this;
    }
    // ...
};
```

And in C++2a, simplify it to:

```
Weighted& operator+=(const Weighted<T>& other)
    requires(has_plus_equal<T, T>::value && has_time_equal<T, double>::value)
{ /*..*/ }
```